# Can't import 'HDF5Matrix' from keras.utils

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am using Google Colab, and i tried to import HDF5Matrix class from keras.utils or keras.utils..io_utils, but i keep getting an error as you can see in the picture below:

The error is :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'HDF5Matrix' from 'tensorflow.keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/keras/utils/__init__.py)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on 2.4.1.

```
print(tf.version.VERSION) # 2.4.1
```

As a **workaround**:

pls try to go to the previous version and it should work okay.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.3.1 # install 2.3.1
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

print(tf.version.VERSION)
from tensorflow.keras.utils import HDF5Matrix
```

Comment: Now, i have another error after reading the h5 file which is : 'TypeError: Indexing elements must be in increasing order'

Comment: oh okay. To reproduce this SO members would need the file unless missing parameters.

Comment: if you have the answer please drop it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67292954/getting-errors-when-using-hdf5matrix-typeerror-indexing-elements-must-be-in-inc