# Getting errors when using HDF5Matrix TypeError: Indexing elements must be in increasing order

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I use HDF5Matrix for my project as we can see in the picture below, when i open the files and try to split the data i get this error:

```
TypeError: Indexing elements must be in increasing order
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), including the section on *do not post images of code or images of error messages*.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/628#issuecomment-495669916) similar thread .